# Splitting an input string with objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am using ASIHTTPREQUEST in an iPhone project to get some data that looks something like this (as an NSString):

```
name:daniel, age:22, occupation:runner, name:greg, age:32, occupation:plumber
```

and I want to parse these into dictionaries or arrays so that I can get all names, or all occupations etc.

How can I do this in objective-c?

Thanks

Comment: your string looks like json, if it is json the use json parser to parse your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use NSString's `-componentsSeparatedByString:` method with a separator string of `@", "` to break the string up into separate substrings, one for each key/value pair. Then you can use it again with a separator of `@":"` to break each substring into a key and a value, and insert these into a dictionary.

Another way is to use NSScanner to scan through your input string, taking the keys and values sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after. I some decent example code here - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html